Is glibc's behavior around localtime_r and TZ compliant to POSIX
I was in the progress of porting some code to use localtime_r instead of localtime to make it more thread-safe, but ran into a very interesting difference between localtime and localtime_r, and it seems unclear to me reading both the glibc ctime(3) man page and the POSIX spec for localtime_r if glibc's behavior is compliant. (I at the minimum find it very surprising, but that doesn't mean it's a bug of course.)
My program is as follows:
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    time_t t;
    struct tm u;

    time(&t);

    localtime_r(&t, &u);
    // u = *localtime(&t);
    printf("%ld\n", u.tm_gmtoff);

    setenv("TZ", "UTC+2", 1);
    localtime_r(&t, &u);
    // u = *localtime(&t);
    printf("%ld\n", u.tm_gmtoff);

    tzset();
    localtime_r(&t, &u);
    // u = *localtime(&t);
    printf("%ld\n", u.tm_gmtoff);
}

In my timezone (Mountain Time), this prints
-25200
-25200
-7200

If I replace all the localtime_r calls with the commented out localtime calls, I get
-25200
-7200
-7200

Looking at the glibc source code, localtime_r calls tzset_internal with always=0, meaning it only reads TZ env var if tzset_internal has not been called yet.
The standard says (from POSIX 2024 localtime_r() but earlier versions say the same):

Local timezone information is used as though localtime() calls tzset().

(and tzset is indeed required to read TZ). Then later,

Unlike localtime(), the localtime_r() function is not required to set tzname. If localtime_r() sets tzname, it shall also set daylight and timezone. If localtime_r() does not set tzname, it shall not set daylight and shall not set timezone.

The glibc man pages say pretty much the same thing.
This seems somewhat unclear to me if localtime_r is required to read an updated TZ value. localtime definitely is, and I understand that reading TZ and setting tzname are probably generally coupled in implementations, but from a spec standpoint I would assume that without a specific mention of localtime_r being allowed to not read TZ, it should have to follow localtime behavior.
So, is this a bug or just surprising but otherwise compliant behavior? Should I consider calling tzset() before localtime_r calls if I want them to have the same behavior as localtime?

localtime_r() isn't supposed to modify any static data. tzset() uses static data to hold the timezone information. So localtime_r() doesn't call it, or do the equivalent of calling it.
It would be possible for it to check the TZ environment variable and store the timezone information in local data of the call. But the performance impact of doing this on every call would be significant, and POSIX doesn't require it. Nowhere in the description of localtime_r() does it say that it acts like it uses tzset() internally.
It would probably be optimal for there to be a tzset_r() function that fills in a given data structure with timezone information (and I would propose that it should take the timezone name as a parameter, rather than using an environment variable), and this could be passed to localtime_r(). But that's not how they specified it.

Source for "localtime_r() isn't supposed to modify any static data."? My reading of the spec just says it needs to be thread safe, and glibc's implementation absolutely does modify static data (if localtime[_r] hasn't been called yet)

If it only does it the first time, that seems safe (assuming it uses a mutex to protect against concurrent calls).

Modifying static data can be thread safe with proper synchronization

I'm not just talking about thread-safety, but about the general purpose of localtime_r() that each call should be independent.

Note that the POSIX specification for tzset()
includes the paragraph on 'Application Usage' (heading in 'shout case'):

Since the ctime(), localtime(), mktime(), strftime(), and strftime_l() functions are required to set timezone information as if by calling tzset(), there is no need for an explicit tzset() call before using these functions. However, portable applications should call tzset() explicitly before using localtime_r() because setting timezone information is optional for that function.

The answer to your second question, therefore, is "Yes; you should call tzset() before using localtime_r()" — if you've not used any of the other functions that are required to set timezone information "as if by calling tzset()".
My impression is that the behaviour exhibited by Glibc is acceptable according to POSIX.  However, that's not a strong answer.

Very nice find there, seems tzset is the answer. Thanks!
